# c++ why I do not get compile error when I call non const method from ref member inside const method

Tags: c++

why I can call non const method from ref member inside const method?
I am expected to get compile error like in case if m_a were not reference type.
run on http://cpp.sh/

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
    void nonConstMethodOfA()
    {
        std::cout << "nonConstMethodOfA is called" << "!\n";
    }
};

class B
{
    public:
    B(A& a)
    : m_a(a)
    {
        constMethodOfB();
    }

    private:
    A& m_a;
    void constMethodOfB() const
    {
        m_a.nonConstMethodOfA();
    }
};

int main()
{
  A varA;
  B varB(varA);
}
```

Comment: @juanchopanza: I guess the OP envisions `const` as transitive, maybe like in D (I don't really know D, but I know that Andrei A. worked on transitive constness in D).

Comment: @juanchopanza I am expected to get compile error like in case if m_a were not reference type.

Comment: @juanchopanza Done.

Comment: @TM constness of an object doesn't propagate through reference or pointer members of the object. If you want those semantics you've got to implement them yourself through accessors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const A &` means "a reference to a const A"

`A &` means "a reference to a mutable A"

A reference cannot be reassigned, so `A &` also implicitly means "a const reference to a mutable A".

Comment: actually I had the same expectations as OP. I do understand that `A` itself is `const` anyhow, but still I am a bit confused. Is it not possible to have a reference member to a non-const object B such that through the reference I cannot change B (through the reference) in a `const` method of A?

Comment: There is a [`propagate_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) in proposals. After C++17 and `operator dot` overload, you will be able to write similar reference wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Const member function means your `this` will point to a const object, thus `this->fn()` can only be called if `fn()` is const. It doesn't lock the type, nor any similar-typed input parameters or globals. You can, however, specify those as const as well if you wish.

Comment: "doesn't lock [...] members" I dont understand. Isnt `struct { int a; void foo() const { a++; }` wrong, because it tries to mutate `a` ?

Comment: @tobi303 yes, but that's not what the OP's code is doing. The member var `m_a` is simply a reference to some concrete object, not an *instance* of a concrete object. As a reference, it is implicitly immutable post initialization anyway (which I think you already understand), so nothing changes the `m_a` member. I concur with Cheers. It appears the OP was expecting `const` to be transitive through non-const reference members, which it is not (yet, C++17 has potential).

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, but still I find this answer misleading. From reading this one might expect that the above example is fine. Consider `struct { int& a; void foo() const { a++; }` as I understand it, the member itself `a` is indeed `const` in `foo` (but that doesnt make the object it references `const`) ie. the constness of `this` implies constness of its members (but not anything the members might be referencing or pointing to)

Comment: I completely concur with your criticism on that regard. Amplified with the watered-down version of [the OP's code **here**](http://ideone.com/SijUNN), that goes the extra mile to move the concrete object along side the member var referencing it. It appears I probably misunderstood your comment, and I think there is a common reason *neither* of us up-ticked this answer.

Comment: EDIT: Removed the word 'members' to avoid confusion on this one.